# Sending binary data to gets()

Tags: shell, stdin

I have a victim program (with a buffer overrun vulnerability): it uses gets() to write into a fixed-sized buffer.

Suppose I put shellcode into a file SC.  Then I run

```
$ ./victim < SC
Input your data: 
$
```

The reason the shellcode does not seem to work is this: SC is redirected to the victim, injects the shellcode, causes a shell to spawn, but the spawned shell finds its stdin is closed, so immediately exits.

I tried `expect` for the injection, but `expect` bombs after the shell spawns.

It seems like the only practical way is to get the shellcode into my mouse's paste buffer so I can inject it while retaining the keyboard as the input device.  But I have no idea how to get binary data into my paste buffer.

Any ideas on how to get around this issue?

Comment: Instead of doing this via the clipboard, can't you inject the shellcode through a pipe? If you don't close it, the spawned shell won't die because of a closed stdin.

Comment: @lgeorget Can you elaborate?  `$ cat SC | ./victim` has the same problem because the EOF from the `cat` is seen by the shell, so it terminates.

Comment: Turns out `$ cat SC - | ./victim` works.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that with a simple script in which you print your special characters.

For example, in Perl, you can print any character by specifying its hexadecimal code. For example:
`perl -e 'print "\x54\x0A"'` prints a 'T' followed by a new line.

You can then copy the text printed, even if it not visible. Of course, your terminal must be in raw mode.

Comment: hmm, wait a little before voting up. I've already done such things but it's not really as easy as that...

Comment: I use PuTTY... no idea how to get this "raw mode" you speak of.  But if I could, that would solve my problem.

Comment: At the low level, there is an ioctl(2) for that. In a shell, I usually get the "raw mode" through socat(1).

Answer (score 2):

A solution to this problem (which someone ran into in the same context) is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509045/execve-bin-sh-0-0-in-a-pipe